# How to get correct functioning of ± in android calculator?

Tags: java, android, calculator

I am working on an android Calculator application. I find that my Calculator shows:

```
6 + (-5) = -10 instead of 6 + (-5) = 1
6 − (-5) = 0 instead of 6 − (-5) = 11
6 × (-5) = 25 instead of 6 × (-5) = -30
6 ÷ (-5) = 1 instead of 6 ÷ (-5) = -1.2
6 % (-5) = 0.25 instead of 6 % (-5) = -0.3
```

and

```
(-5) + 6 = 1
(-5) − 6 = -11
(-5) × 6 = -30
(-5) ÷ 6 = -0.8333333333333334
(-5) % 6 = -0.3
```

It works fine when I use `±` for the first number but when I use it for the second number, it shows a wrong answer. It happens with all the numbers, not only `6` and `5`. I am using Eclipse to make this app.

My question is "How do i fix this problem?" i.e.; `6 + (-5) = 1`; `6 − (-5) = 11`; `6 × (-5) = -30`; `6 ÷ (-5) = -1.2`; `6 % (-5) = -0.3` and so on ..... for all the other numbers.

This is the Code I used:

```
ImageButton btnPlus;
ImageButton btnMin;
ImageButton btnMul;
ImageButton btnDiv;
ImageButton btnPercent;
ImageButton btnPlusmin;
ImageButton btnEqual;
TextView txtDisplay;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btnPlus = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnPlus);
    btnMin = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnMin);
    btnMul = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnMul);
    btnDiv = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnDiv);
    btnPercent = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnPercent);
    btnPlusmin = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnPlusmin);
    btnEqual = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnEqual);
    txtDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtDisplay);

    btnPlus.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnMin.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnMul.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnDiv.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnPercent.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnPlusmin.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnEqual.setOnClickListener(this);

}

int clear_flag = 0;
String sign_flag = "";
Double total = 0.0;
int last_button = 0;

public void showsign(String sign) {
    if (last_button == R.id.btnPlus || last_button == R.id.btnMin || last_button == R.id.btnMul || last_button == R.id.btnDiv) {
    }
    else {
        clear_flag = 1;
        Double newNumber = Double.parseDouble(txtDisplay.getText().toString());
        if (sign_flag == "" || sign_flag == "=") {
            total = newNumber;
            txtDisplay.setText(total.toString());
        }
        else if (sign_flag == "+") {
            total = total + newNumber;
            txtDisplay.setText(total.toString());
        }
        else if (sign_flag == "-") {
            total = total - newNumber;
            txtDisplay.setText(total.toString());
        }
        else if (sign_flag == "*") {
            total = total * newNumber;
            txtDisplay.setText(total.toString());
        }
        else if (sign_flag == "/") {
            total = total / newNumber;
            txtDisplay.setText(total.toString());
        }
    }

    sign_flag = sign;

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if (v.getId() == R.id.btnPlus) {
        showsign("+");
    }
    else if (v.getId() == R.id.btnMin) {
        showsign("-");
    }
    else if (v.getId() == R.id.btnMul) {
        showsign("*");
    }
    else if (v.getId() == R.id.btnDiv) {
        showsign("/");
    }
    else if (v.getId() == R.id.btnEqual) {
        Double newNumber = Double.parseDouble(txtDisplay.getText().toString());
        if (sign_flag == "+") {
            total = total + newNumber;
            txtDisplay.setText(total.toString());
        }
        else if (sign_flag == "-") {
            total = total - newNumber;
            txtDisplay.setText(total.toString());
        }
        else if (sign_flag == "*") {
            total = total * newNumber;
            txtDisplay.setText(total.toString());
        }
        else if (sign_flag == "/") {
            total = total / newNumber;
            txtDisplay.setText(total.toString());
        }
        else if (sign_flag == "%") {
            total = (total * newNumber)/100;
            txtDisplay.setText(total.toString());
        }

        sign_flag = "=";

    }
    else if (v.getId() == R.id.btnPlusmin) {
        Double newNumber = Double.parseDouble(txtDisplay.getText().toString());
        total = newNumber * (-1);
        txtDisplay.setText(total.toString());
    }
    else if (v.getId() == R.id.btnPercent) {
        sign_flag = "%";
        clear_flag = 1;
        Double newNumber = Double.parseDouble(txtDisplay.getText().toString());
        total = newNumber;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When doing string comparisons you really need to do sign_flag.equals("+") instead of '==', because this will only check the location of the addresses.  String comparisons don't work in that manner.  There might be more, but start with that.

**Edit:**

The mathematical logic signifies that the first number in those equations is getting multiplied by (-1) and then having one added on to it.  That is the pattern.  So, that should be followed to see where your calculations are going wrong.

What is meant:

6 + (-5) != -10 but ((6 * -1) + 1) + (-5) = -10

and

6 − (-5) != 0 but ((6 * -1) + 1) - (-5) = 0

and

6 × (-5) != 25 but ((6 * -1) + 1) x (-5) = 25

That's the pattern I am seeing that is being calculated.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much.

Modifying my code by changing

```
else if (v.getId() == R.id.btnPlusmin) {
    Double newNumber = Double.parseDouble(txtDisplay.getText().toString());
    total = newNumber * (-1);
    txtDisplay.setText(total.toString());
}
```

to

```
else if (v.getId() == R.id.btnPlusmin) {
    Double newNumber = Double.parseDouble(txtDisplay.getText().toString());
    subtotal = newNumber * (-1);
    txtDisplay.setText(subtotal.toString());
}
```

and adding

```
Double subtotal = 0.0;
```

to

```
int clear_flag = 0;
String sign_flag = "";
Double total = 0.0;
int last_button = 0;
```

solved my problem.

So, my new Code is:

```
ImageButton btnPlus;
ImageButton btnMin;
ImageButton btnMul;
ImageButton btnDiv;
ImageButton btnPercent;
ImageButton btnPlusmin;
ImageButton btnEqual;
TextView txtDisplay;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btnPlus = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnPlus);
    btnMin = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnMin);
    btnMul = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnMul);
    btnDiv = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnDiv);
    btnPercent = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnPercent);
    btnPlusmin = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnPlusmin);
    btnEqual = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnEqual);
    txtDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtDisplay);

    btnPlus.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnMin.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnMul.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnDiv.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnPercent.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnPlusmin.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnEqual.setOnClickListener(this);

}

int clear_flag = 0;
String sign_flag = "";
Double total = 0.0;
Double subtotal = 0.0;
int last_button = 0;

public void showsign(String sign) {
    if (last_button == R.id.btnPlus || last_button == R.id.btnMin || last_button == R.id.btnMul || last_button == R.id.btnDiv) {
    }
    else {
        clear_flag = 1;
        Double newNumber = Double.parseDouble(txtDisplay.getText().toString());
        if (sign_flag == "" || sign_flag == "=") {
            total = newNumber;
            txtDisplay.setText(total.toString());
        }
        else if (sign_flag == "+") {
            total = total + newNumber;
            txtDisplay.setText(total.toString());
        }
        else if (sign_flag == "-") {
            total = total - newNumber;
            txtDisplay.setText(total.toString());
        }
        else if (sign_flag == "*") {
            total = total * newNumber;
            txtDisplay.setText(total.toString());
        }
        else if (sign_flag == "/") {
            total = total / newNumber;
            txtDisplay.setText(total.toString());
        }
    }

    sign_flag = sign;

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if (v.getId() == R.id.btnPlus) {
        showsign("+");
    }
    else if (v.getId() == R.id.btnMin) {
        showsign("-");
    }
    else if (v.getId() == R.id.btnMul) {
        showsign("*");
    }
    else if (v.getId() == R.id.btnDiv) {
        showsign("/");
    }
    else if (v.getId() == R.id.btnEqual) {
        Double newNumber = Double.parseDouble(txtDisplay.getText().toString());
        if (sign_flag == "+") {
            total = total + newNumber;
            txtDisplay.setText(total.toString());
        }
        else if (sign_flag == "-") {
            total = total - newNumber;
            txtDisplay.setText(total.toString());
        }
        else if (sign_flag == "*") {
            total = total * newNumber;
            txtDisplay.setText(total.toString());
        }
        else if (sign_flag == "/") {
            total = total / newNumber;
            txtDisplay.setText(total.toString());
        }
        else if (sign_flag == "%") {
            total = (total * newNumber)/100;
            txtDisplay.setText(total.toString());
        }

        sign_flag = "=";

    }
    else if (v.getId() == R.id.btnPlusmin) {
        Double newNumber = Double.parseDouble(txtDisplay.getText().toString());
        subtotal = newNumber * (-1);
        txtDisplay.setText(subtotal.toString());
    }
    else if (v.getId() == R.id.btnPercent) {
        sign_flag = "%";
        clear_flag = 1;
        Double newNumber = Double.parseDouble(txtDisplay.getText().toString());
        total = newNumber;
    }
}
```